# Troubles with Promises

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, ionic-framework

I'm doing an Ionic project and I'm getting a little bit frustrated whit promises and '.then()' although I've read a lot of documentation everywhere.

The case is that I have one provider with the functions `loadClients` and `getWaybills`.
The first one gets all the clients that have waybills and the second one gets all the waybills from one concrete client.

```
  loadClients() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('http://localhost/waybills?fields=descr1_sped&idUser='+ this.id)
        .map(res => res)
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.data = data.json();
          resolve(this.data);
        });
    });
  }

  // GET WAYBILLS
  getWaybills(client) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('http://localhost/waybills/?stato=0&idUser='+ this.id +'&descr1_sped='+ client)
        .map(res => res)
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.data = data.json();
          resolve(this.data);
        });
    });
  }
```

On the other hand, on the component `welcome.ts` I have a function `loadWaybills` which is called on the view load and is executing the following code, my idea is to get all the clients and then get the respective waybills of each one. Then I'll take just of the ones that are defined.

The problem is that on the second `.then()` instead of getting the variable data I'm getting just undefined... I've understood that if you put a synchronous code inside `.then()` can be properly executed and work with the "data" which is the result of the promise. Why am I getting this undefined?

```
  loadWaybills() {
    //We first load the clients
    this.waybills.loadClients()
      .then(data => {
        this.waybill = data;
        var preClients = this.waybill;
        this.clients = [];
        //Here we're deleting duplicated clients and getWaybills of them)
        for (let i = 0; i < preClients.length; i++) {
          if (this.clients.indexOf(preClients[i].descr1_sped) == -1) {
            this.waybills.getWaybills(preClients[i].descr1_sped)
            .then(data => {
              **//Here we'll check if the clients has waybills or not**
              this.clientWaybills[i] = data;
              this.clients.push(preClients[i].descr1_sped)
            });
          }
        }
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say because we don't know what the API is meant to return. For example, there may be a missing field somewhere from the first GET and now for the second one, it returns as undefined sometimes. If it only returns undefined sometimes, a simple solution to this, would be to check that the value is defined before assigning it to the variable.

If it always returns as undefined and shouldn't, try to debug the code and make sure that the values are present before the second .then.